# How to sign the application for running it on the iPhone device

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I am new to the iPhone application development.
I have apple developer connection. Please any one here can help i finding the way to get my code sign and run it on the iPhone device?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 4):

Hotcocoa has made a really nice video tutorial showing [how to deploy you app on the iphone](http://blip.tv/file/1596565)

Answer (score 2):

Have you enrolled in an iPhone Developer Program? If you have, there's the Developer Program Portal on http://developer.apple.com/iphone. In the portal you will find instructions on certificates and provisioning profiles. I had a little trouble at first myself, but when I read (and followed) their instructions properly it was easy.

If you have not enrolled in an iPhone Developer Program, you're out of luck.