# how to generate valid code-signing certificate in a keychain for iphone procedure?

Tags: iphone

i am done with my iphone application.Now i just want to make a binary file of the application...For that i need a code signing certificate.. as i know i can make it with "code signing certificate" or "iphone developer" or "iphone distribution"... So i just wanna add anew certificate out there... so can anyone help me with that plz tell me the procedure.......

thanx in advance..

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843206/how-to-sign-the-application-for-running-it-on-the-iphone-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to developer center and use Certificate Assistant from there. It explains all. Remember to create your public and private keys in Keychain before doing other steps.